# How to set Dapper connection string in the top of the application once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, .net-7.0

I using Dapper in my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API.

I have a lot of functions looks like that:

```
public async Task<int> InsertTableObject(TableObject tableObject)
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"));
    var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(
        "INSERT INTO [table_object] (name, create_at) VALUES (@Name, @CreateAt)",
        tableObject);
    return result;
}
```

Each time I open new connection and pass the connection string:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")
```

I wounder if it possible to do it once in the `program.cs` and use the connection in those functions? I don't mean to do like that:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public YourRepositoryClass(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

private SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"));
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

because it just wrap the Dapper connection (instead I want to configure to use "MyDB" connection string) and every time using the Dapper SQL class then it will read from the configuration.

Is it possible to do that? Something like:

```
// program.cs
...
Dapper.setConnectionString(Configuration["MyDB"]);
...
var app = builder.Build();
...

// foo.cs:
class Foo {
  public async Task<int> InsertTableObject(TableObject tableObject)
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(); // or without new? Dapper.Connection?
        var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(
            "INSERT INTO [table_object] (name, create_at) VALUES (@Name, @CreateAt)",
            tableObject);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having your SQL written directly in your business classes, create a class (or even several classes) dedicated to handle storage - and handle all your SQL stuff there.   You can then inject the connection string to the class(es) In that layer and handle the creation of SqlConnection instances in a single method, not exposed to the rest of your application.

Comment: But why to wrap Dapper? it's the DAL as you suggest. if I create class just "wrap" the dapper then I possibly add complex code to my application because as the application will grow I need to add more functions to DAL to support Dapper functions. those functions are just a pipe for Dapper.

Comment: You can wrap dapper connection to a connection factory. Which would just replace this line -> `var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"));` Similar to the answer you got but without the execute part...

Comment: Having an abstraction layer over your storage makes it easier to maintain the code: For instance, it's much easier to write automation tests or reusable code when it's detached from outside dependencies. More over, if you ever decide to change ORM or storage, it would be much easier to simply write a new DAL than to rewrite all the parts in your code that handles storage.

Answer (score 3):

you can create wrapper around Dapper something like this :

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Dapper;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public interface IDbService
    {
        Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string query, object parameters);
    }


    public class DbService : IDbService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DbService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string query, object parameters)
        {
            await using var connection = GetSqlConnection();
            return await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"));
        }
    }
}
```

register in DI :

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbService,DbService>();
```

and use as follows :

```
 public class Foo
 {
     private readonly IDbService _dbService;

     public Foo(IDbService dbService)
     {
         _dbService = dbService;
     }

     public async Task<int> InsertTableObject(TableObject tableObject)
     {         
          return _dbService.ExecuteAsync(@"INSERT INTO [table_object] (name, create_at) 
                                              VALUES (@Name, @CreateAt)", tableObject);
     }
 }
```

Comment: But why wrap the Dapper and not use it itself? Dapper doesn't support that? seems to me that wrap everything makes the code more complex.

Comment: this is a abstraction and it is a completely standard solution in oop programming languages.
Contrary to what you said, this prevents complexity. In fact, you manage complexity in one place, which makes your code cleaner and makes changes easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement an `IConnectionProvider` interface that return a new IDbConnection, and then use it with Dapper or anything else.

This is a simple implementation:

```cs
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public interface IConnectionProvider {
    IDbConnection GetConnection();
}

public class ConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider {
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ConnectionProvider(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection() {
        // you could also change logic to create the connection
        // e.g. getting connection name from a configuration value
        return new SqlConnection(
            _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"));
    }
}
```

You could register it as singleton in `porgram.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionProvider, ConnectionProvider>();
```

And then use it

```
class Foo {
    IConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;
    public Foo(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
        _connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
    }

    public async Task<int> InsertTableObject(TableObject tableObject) {
        using var connection = _connectionProvider.GetConnection(); 
        var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(
            "INSERT INTO [table_object] (name, create_at) VALUES (@Name, @CreateAt)",
            tableObject);
        return result;
    }
}
```